# synchronous network audio

Tags: linux, audio, sync, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synced audio ouput on multiple machines? VLC? hardware solutions?](https://superuser.com/questions/31647/synced-audio-ouput-on-multiple-machines-vlc-hardware-solutions)

I'd like to have an audio transmission shared among computers on a LAN.  Although there are various systems to do this -- shoutcast/icecast, pulseaudio, etc. -- I'm not aware of any that provide synchronization.  I'd like to have different computers in the house playing the same audio, and have the same sample playing at the same time.  Is there a system which can do this?

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/31647/synced-audio-ouput-on-multiple-machines-vlc-hardware-solutions

Comment: @quack - I agree

Comment: Missed that one in my search.. Thanks, folks.